# navbar not going hamburger - bootstrap / Flask

Tags: css, navbar, bootstrap-4

My navbar does not display correctly for small screen sizes: https://www.paulahuevo.com/

I use Bootstrap Material Design with Flask and have the following code for the nav-bar:

```
<!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark purple">
        <div class='container'>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">

            <ul class="navbar-nav">
            {% for href, id, caption in navigation_bar %}

                <li{% if id == active_page %} class="active"{% endif %}>

                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ href|e }}">{{ caption|e }}</a>
                </li>

            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I never worked with bootstrap, what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing some of the navbar components.

For example, you are missing the `nav-item` class on the `li`s.

Also, you need the navbar-toggler.

Check out this template as a working example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

One follow-up question: On mobile the fonts are still tiny (but this is an issue with the whole page). What am I missing there? It detects mobile, because it directly shows the hambuger menu instead of the navbar.

Comment: I found the solution, in case anyone has the same problem just add this code and it works:

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">